# Blank menu.lst file after installing Ubuntu9.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, grub

I just installed Ubuntu 9.10 on my PC. I have Windows XP as the primary OS.

I am trying to set XP as the default OS with the following command in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

After that it should display something like this:

[image]

Instead it is showing a blank `menu.lst` file.

What's the problem? What should I do?

Comment: This question could have some answers for you (though not a duplicate): http://superuser.com/questions/50684/how-to-fix-grub-after-windows-breaks-it-and-how-to-edit-the-grub-menu

Comment: ("this question can have answers for you"... always a strange thing to say :])

Comment: @ Gnoupi Nothing helpful.My problem is different

Comment: nope.  ubuntu 9.10 has switched to Grub2 which is __just different__.  no menu.lst anymore.  maybe look for a `grub.cfg` or similar? i haven't installed it yet so i can't tell you how to fix.  :-/

Comment: I thought that one of the given commands to re-setup it would as well regenerate the menu.lst, pity.

Comment: @quack, then that explains the "empty" file, it's just not existing yet. Post it as answer, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments point out the new Grub is just setup differently. Now you'll want to make your personalized settings changes in the file: **/etc/default/grub**

At a terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now you can change the relevant setting (just like the settings you were accustomed to in the previous version).

More information can be found at this helpful thread: [Grub 2 Basics](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275)

Also take note of the section talking about the files contained in: **/etc/grub.d/**

Comment: Oh the joys of getting used to the new syntax of newer version of a bootloader.

Comment: I hear ya, I didn't even know about this until researching this question... the custom file thing is a bit archaic in my eyes... but we're sure to see some helpful config tools built around this... the joy of F/OSS!

Comment: thanks for the info, codeLes, my searches hadn't managed to turn up a handy link like that one.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link.But I was too lazy to read it and in the meantime I found the exact answer.(See my answer)

Comment: @ravi: I guess I should have given a bit more info, I think the answer still fits the context of your question... I'll just organize it a little better...

Answer (score 1):

Following is the exact answer (worked for me perfectly):

Run following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change GRUB__DEFAULT=0  to 4

And then without forget run following command :

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update the grub.

And you are done.

(Found this on [this](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1305399) thread)