# Help with Grub Error 21?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I have a computer with a 640GB Raid 0 as my primary hard drive, running Vista Home Premium 64-bit and a (later added) 1TB drive with Windows 7 on an 800GB Partition and I just installed Ubuntu 9.04 off of a DVD on the remaining space (Roughly 130GB) and I a am getting stuck before GRUB loads. Grub reports 'loading stage 1.5' and 'Error 21'

What can I do to repair this?

Thank you.

*EDIT:*

I've searched a little online and found that other people have been having issues with Raid 0 and Ubuntu. - Will removing the drive which contains the offending GRUB allow me to boot into the Vista partition? Can I even tell which hard drive GRUB was installed on? If yes, how so? How about formatting the linux partition?

Windows Vista repair CD finds no problem with my Vista partition. GRUB is just getting between the BIOS and the Windows Bootloader. At this point I'm ready to ditch the Ubuntu setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Windows 7 over the Ubuntu partition. No Ubuntu for now, but no more GRUB either. good riddance! Windows does what any sane OS with a natural ego would - put its own bootloader in the MBR. Problem Solved - and - I get *2* Windows 7s!

Answer (score 0):

There are some good solutions here - [How to fix GRUB after Windows breaks it, and how to edit the GRUB menu](https://superuser.com/questions/50684/how-to-fix-grub-after-windows-breaks-it-and-how-to-edit-the-grub-menu)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a slightly different issue. GRUB was installed on the raid 0, which ubuntu doesn't want to recognize. The only thing I can boot into now is the Live CD.