# grub is not starting after installing Windows XP to dualboot environment

Tags: grub, multi-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix GRUB after Windows breaks it, and how to edit the GRUB menu](https://superuser.com/questions/50684/how-to-fix-grub-after-windows-breaks-it-and-how-to-edit-the-grub-menu)

I have been using Fedora and Windows 7 for past 6 months. I replaced Windows 7 with Windows XP and I didn't touch Fedora partition (that was in Drive `E:`). However, after I finished installing Windows XP I can't see grub bootloader while starting my PC.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to reinstall Grub. Windows XP got rid of it when you installed it.

Comment: How to reinstall Grub?? Any link, because right now i dont have any Fedora CD. So provide some links

Comment: Can i Mount the image file and boot with that? Will that work?

Comment: @Anto no (if you have no OS loaded what will mount the disk?). Just google "fedora reinstall grub"