# Make a grub menu for 3 hard drives

Tags: grub

I have a machine with a 3 hard drives in it, each with a windows server 2k8 install on it. I'd like a grub menu where you can select which hdd to boot to.

I've already used ubuntu to put grub onto a pendrive which it boots too by default, but i cant figure out what the menu entries need to be.

Comment: another similar question here http://superuser.com/questions/50684/how-to-fix-grub-after-windows-breaks-it-and-how-to-edit-the-grub-menu

Comment: Thats how to boot into ubuntu on a grub thats already setup. I want to know how to setup grub to boot multiple windows installs

Answer (score 0):

open the file /boot/grub/menu.lst with the following command:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

You’ll see a sample section for Windows, which you’ll want to uncomment and add to the boot menu list in whatever position you want it in. (uncomment by removing the #’s)

```
title   Windows 95/98/NT/2000  
root   (hd0,0)  
makeactive  
chainloader   +1
```

Note that you should also verify that hd0,0 is the correct location for Windows. If you had installed Windows on the 4th partition on the drive, then you should change it to (hd0,3)

from [HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/reinstall-ubuntu-grub-bootloader-after-windows-wipes-it-out/)