# linux mint is not starting. grub issues?

Tags: windows, linux, grub, multi-boot

I dual booted my xp installing mint, everything went well, i gave the cd to my friend and he installed linux mint 12  but it's not starting, i mean there's no menu where you choose what OS you want to use, windows 7 is starting automatically, why?

**EDIT** I believe that my friend has lost the grub menu when he installed linux, how to fix it?

Comment: Which of the two computers has the problem?

Comment: his, not mine, the win 7 has the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix GRUB after Windows breaks it, and how to edit the GRUB menu](http://superuser.com/questions/50684/how-to-fix-grub-after-windows-breaks-it-and-how-to-edit-the-grub-menu)