# how to restore GRUB without live CD

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repair grub mbr and /boot using ubuntu 9.04 live CD](https://superuser.com/questions/25168/repair-grub-mbr-and-boot-using-ubuntu-9-04-live-cd)

Hello,

Ubuntu 9.10

I have Ubuntu 9.10 installed on one of my partitions. However, I needed to install Redhat 5.3 on a separate partition. However, doing this broke my GRUB for Ubuntu.

However, I can't boot into my Ubuntu. And I don't have my Live CD.

Is there another way I can restore my GRUB for Ubuntu?

Many thanks,

Comment: RHEL 5.3 or the *really old* Redhat 5.3 (that probably would've installed LILO)?  the most important thing: **can you boot into RedHat?**

Comment: Yes. I can boot into redhat. However. I have finished with redhat now.    And want my Ubuntu back. I have found my Ubuntu LiveCD and have booted from it. However, how do I restore from the LiveCD?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the LiveCD, follow the process documented at [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

**Make sure you're using a LiveCD that matches the version of Ubuntu installed on the computer.**  Especially do not use an Ubuntu 9.10 LiveCD to recover an older version of Ubuntu installed on the drive.

Essentially, the instructions boil down to the comand `grub-install --root-directory=/path/to/boot /dev/sdX`.  They go into good detail about preparing the system for that command, what options to use, and how to verify that you got it right, so I won't reproduce any more of the process here.

Comment: Hmmm, seems like the question title should be changed to match the answer, or vice versa :\