# Recovering Ubuntu after Windows Vista x64 installation

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repair grub mbr and /boot using ubuntu 9.04 live CD](https://superuser.com/questions/25168/repair-grub-mbr-and-boot-using-ubuntu-9-04-live-cd)

Hi there,

how to recover Ubuntu after installing Windows Vista x64? Vista is installed on another HDD partition, however it has probably overwritten the GRUB. I don't have the Ubuntu Live CD. How to do that without the CD?

Thank you in advance for the reply!

Comment: In the future, you should always install Windows first then Linux second as Windows never plays nice with other operating systems and always overwrites the MBR.

Comment: see also the [Super User faq on chroot](http://superuser.com/questions/111152/whats-the-proper-way-to-prepare-chroot-to-recover-a-broken-linux-installation).

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall GRUB. I believe you'll need some kind of LiveCD for this though.