# recover original installed os list

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I have a PC with Ubuntu and windows7 installed on it. Normally before booting, I'd get a list showing the two OS installation and let me chose what I want to boot into.

However recently had issues booting into windows. Now to fix this I did the following

1. booted into windows7 installation disk
2. Went into recovery options
3. Loaded command prompt
4. typed in the following code

   ```
   bootrec /FixMbr
   bootrec /FixBoot
   bootrec /RebuildBcd
   ```

This fixed the boot issue for windows7, however Ubuntu doesn't seem to show up anymore. There is no pre-boot list showing any OS installations. It directly boots into windows

I know I have not formatted any drive so ubuntu should be there somewhere on my drive, is there any way of getting the list of installed OS back???

Comment: Repair GRUB installation

Comment: See: http://superuser.com/a/602931/219655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall grub as the bootrec only restore the loader for Windows. Documentation about how to handle grub is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows).

A summary:
Using the Ubuntu CD (Recommended)

The graphical way

```
Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.

Install and run Boot-Repair
Click "Recommended Repair".
Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.
```

Comment: I dont have a CD on me right now. Can try and download an ISO. However are there any alternative ways of repairing grub??

Answer (score 0):

Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
Install and run Boot-Repair
Click "Recommended Repair".
Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows