# Windows 7 cannot boot after Ubuntu install

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on an unassigned partition, but Windows 7 cannot reboot after choosing it, saying Windows Boot Manager error.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\bcd

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.
```

When I tried to repair I cannot find Windows disk. Then I went to reinstall, cannot find the partitions at all. I checked in Ubuntu, the filesystem type for C:drive is NTFS.

What should I do to get my Windows back?

Answer (score 1):

### BCD Repair

Windows have a tool for this purpose, called [BCDboot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744347%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

> If the system partition has been corrupted, you can use BCDboot to replace the system partition files with new copies of these files from the Windows partition.

When you have booted to the Windows disc, then go to the command prompt (see [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/)) and type the following to recreate the BCD on the C drive:

1. `attrib -r -s -h c:\boot\bcd` - unhide BCD so it can be deleted
2. `del c:\boot\bcd` - delete the current BCD
3. `bcdboot C:\windows` - create a new BCD on the C drive

### Method 2

1. Put the Windows installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when the message indicating `Press any key to boot from CD or DVD...`. appears.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, and a keyboard or another input method, and then click ***Next***.
4. Click ***Repair your computer***.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click ***Next***.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click ***Command Prompt***.
7. Try the ***bootec*** commands and then run StartUp Repair twice from your Windows Disk.  Enter these commands:

   - `bootrec /fixmbr`
   - `bootrec /fixboot`
   - `bootrec /scanos`
   - `bootrec /rebuildbcd`

From here you should be able to boot into Windows again.

If does not work, you can try to solve this problem using Boot Repair (as already mentioned), [`see here`](https://superuser.com/a/602931/219655).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I cannot find my partitions. The path was not found -C:\boot

Comment: This solution will wipe out the grub, which will in turn leave Windows bootable but ubuntu **not** bootable. Check my answer for another solution.

Comment: @moses You have any reference or link to confirm this? *I did not understand why the vote down*.

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot into Ubuntu?

If so try running `sudo update-grub2` That has always fixed windows boot problems for me!

Answer (score 0):

I just started using ubuntu on a few different PCs, and I've found that the tried-and-true solution in all of them is using the [Boot-Repair-disk](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) provided by ubuntu. It has solved nearly every boot problem I've faced so far, and it doesn't require much but a few clicks (ie. no endless terminal/command prompt tinkering).

Try the automatic repair in the boot repair disk, which will scan all installed OS's, re-build the grub and give you startup options for your dual boot system.

Answer (score 0):

if u can't get the disk as they mentioned earlier  just try pressing 
F8 to go to advanced startup then F7 to disable driver signature  it Will automatically start your windows (xp,vista,7or8)  ran
tanks